# How to connect to a Sybase SQL Anywhere v5.0 server using ODBC + .net

Tags: .net, odbc, sqlanywhere

I have a old myDemo.db file, thats was created by Sybase SQL Anywhere 5.0. 
I need to create a Windows app to access that DB, I have tried all possibles connections strings (using ODBC), but none worked.

I have installed the Sybase SQL Anywhere 5.0 server and client app, created the server locally(by service manager) and I can access by ISQL, but when I try by a .net windows app, doesn't work.

Recently, I installed the Sybase latest version, but when I try to create the myDemo.db, using the Personal Server app, don't work, "myDemo.db was created by a different version of the software".

Can someone help ? What do I need to use to create the ODBC and connect to that database?
Thanks

The error that i get, when trying with ODBC:

ERROR [08001] [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Unable to connect to database server
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).

Code

```
string conStr = "Driver={Sybase SQL Anywhere 5.0};Dsn=Prima;uid=dba;PWD=test";
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conStr);
conn.Open();

string sql = "select count(*) from ClienteCorretor";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: You might want to ask at http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com, which is a Q&A forum dedicated to Sybase SQL Anywhere. SQL Anywhere version 5 is over 15 years old, but there are probably people there who can help.

Comment: Btw, I installed Sybase Anywhere 12 and tried to start a Personal Server with myDemo.db, but I got the message: "myDemo.db was created by a different version of the software, you must rebuild this database to use with this version". How can I do that?

Comment: This command: `dbunload -c dbf=myDemo.db;uid=dba;pwd=<dba password> -an newDemo.db` will create a new database called newDemo.db and reload the old database into it. There are other `-a` and `-e` switches that you can use to configure the new database.

Comment: @Bruno, did you find a solution ? May you post it ? I'm facing the same situation... Thanks.